# VB.net regex DotAll can't make it work

Tags: regex, vb.net

Trying to parse a txt file in VB.net using visual basic 2010 and Regular expression.

In Python I could call the DotAll modifier to make `.*` mean new lines, But can't seem to make it work in VB.Net. even using `(?s)`

Here is what I got

```
Dim test As Match = Regex.Match(LogFile, "\s+Following Loads are summed\n\s+gravity(?s).*?(F.*?)mN")

If test.Success Then
    Dim results As String = test.Groups(1).Value
    Console.WriteLine(results)
Else
    Console.WriteLine(" did not work")
End If
```

I'm using this website to test it out and works there:

http://regex101.com/r/pD6zV6/2

result should be a string containing this

```
"F(x)    F(y)    F(z) :  0.000000E+000,    0.000000E+000,    -4.973469E+007"
```

The Text file is always the same layout, but changing the word Gravity with others, so I will need to loop through a list of words and get that line for each case.

Can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work in the script, it works on the test website.

Cheers
Kiko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add any modifiers. `(.|\n)*?` would do a non-greedy match of any character zero or more times.

```
\sFollowing Loads are summed.*\n\s+gravity(?:.|\n)*?\s*(.*?)\s*mN
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pD6zV6/7)

OR

```
\s+Following Loads are summed\n\s+gravity[\S\s]*?(F.*?)\s*mN
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pD6zV6/4)

Comment: tried that as well, doesn't seem to work, (?s) also needs to be inside the "" right?!

Comment: yep, it needs to present inside the double quotes.

Comment: so yeah, it doesn't work. I don't really know a lot about VB.net, maybe I need to import the modifiers o something, because the regex is working if it does not uses multiline

Comment: nop, didn't work. I made it work using "\sFollowing Loads are summed.*\n\s+gravity\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n(.*)mN" but this isn't very good because if the number of lines change it will not work

Comment: Both works, awesome. Going to try and figure out what you need

Comment: If Avinash's first suggestion doesn't work but the later ones do, it's probably because your text uses `\r\n` to separate lines.  If I'm right, it's the addition of `.*` before the first `\n` in your regex that fixed it.  I tested it in RegexBuddy, which lets me specify the line separator; your regex works when I choose `\n`, but not when I choose `\r\n`.  When I copy the text from there into regex101, it always succeeds, leading me to suspect the site is changing the line separators without telling anyone.